# IllegalArgumentException from Executors.newFixedThreadPool()

Tags: java, multithreading

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Unknown Source)
>   at alerts.email.VinrEmailNotification.main(VinrEmailNotification.java:50)

This is my exception. How can I solve it? This is my code:

```
package alerts.email;  

import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.util.Properties; 
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService; 
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;  
import org.apache.log4j.Logger; 
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;  
import alerts.utils.Constants;  

/** The main entry point for the application which  
 *  creates a pool of threads for probing the  
 *  MessagesInTable, messages_sent_table and the  
 *  retrytable and uses the Java 5 Executor service  
 *  to run all the threads in the pool as parallel   
 *  tasks  
 *  
 *  @author Sunil Tuppale  
 *  @date July-19-2010  
 *  @version 1.0  
 */ 

public class VinrEmailNotification {     

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VinrEmailNotification.class);      
    public static void main(String[] args) {                  
        Properties logProperties = null;         
        try {             //settings for logging             
            String fileName = System.getenv("LOG_PROPERTIES_FILE");
            if (fileName == null)
                fileName="vinralerts.properties";
            logProperties = new Properties(System.getProperties());
            logProperties.load(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(logProperties);
            logger.debug("Logging initialized in VinrEmailNotification class ");          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        /*          
         * create a thread pool with four threads
         */         
        int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = ConnectionPoolProvider.getInstance().getThreadPoolSize();
        ExecutorService messagesInTableTPExecSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        //ExecutorService messagesSentTableTPExecSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Constants.THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        //ExecutorService retryTableTPExecSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Constants.THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        /*          
         * place four tasks in the work queue for the thread pool         */
        for( int i = 0; i < THREAD_POOL_SIZE; i++ ) {
            messagesInTableTPExecSvc.execute(new MessagesInTableProbe(i));
            //messagesSentTableTPExecSvc.execute(new MessagesSentTableProbe(i));
            //retryTableTPExecSvc.execute(new RetryTableProbe(i));
        }
        /*
         * prevent other tasks from being added to the queue
         */         
        messagesInTableTPExecSvc.shutdown();
        //messagesSentTableTPExecSvc.shutdown()
        //retryTableTPExecSvc.shutdown(); 
        //ConnectionPoolProvider.getInstance().getDataSource().release();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile Error: illegal start of expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680528/compile-error-illegal-start-of-expression)

Comment: How about formatting?!

Comment: Please, before posting your code always format it. It's impossible to read right now.

Comment: @SalmaanC no. This isn't a compiler error.

Comment: You should load the code for the JVM into your IDE so you can see where the actual exception is happening and figure it out by yourself.

Comment: @Gray That is one option (and a nice one to have at hand). I think one should start by simply reading the documentation of the method that throws the exception, the information ought to be found there, and as I say in my answer, this is the case here (I did verify in the source that there was no other possibility, I admit, but that was indeed superfluous).

Answer (score 6):

It means that `THREAD_POOL_SIZE` is 0 or negative.

From the documentation of [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-):

> **Throws:**
>
> `IllegalArgumentException - if nThreads <= 0`

The solution obviously is to make sure that `ConnectionPoolProvider.getInstance().getThreadPoolSize()` returns a positive number (at least 1). How you do that, I believe that you know best since it’s your own code. Or you may use a default value (say, 1) in case the provider does not provide a valid value.

Comment: Also had a similar problem, only that in my case, I was accidentally setting coreThreads > maxThreads. Eg. core - 10, max- 5. After correcting this (by inverting them), the exception disappeared. There must be a constraint check that enforces that max threads should always be greater or equal than core threads.